# Serialize and deserialize unknown JSON to binary

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization, serde, bincode

I'm writing a microservice that takes a json object as input. This json object is only partially known and therefore the struct to which I map it looks like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Incoming {
    uri: String,
    payload: serde_json::Value,
    id: String
}
```

I then want to publish this to a RabbitMQ queue so I serialize it using `bincode`:

```
let incoming = serde_json::from_slice::<Incoming>(&incoming).expect("Fail to serialize");
// This line fails:
bincode::serialize(&incoming).expect("Failed to deserialize to binary");
```

The receiving service (the consumer) fails to deserialize this (even though it has the exact same model) and results in `Err(DeserializeAnyNotSupported)`.

From my understanding this comed from the `serde_json::Value`-part of the struct.
So how do I serialize a partially unknown JSON-object to binary in order to deserialize it on the receiving service?

Comment: Is payload a single object?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios It is a single object but it can ( and most likely will ) be nested objects. If that is what you wonder?

Comment: Yes. What is the operation which fails?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios The deserializing once we consume the message from RabbitMQ: 
`bincode::deserialize::<Incoming>(delivery.data.as_slice());`

Comment: It seems the json object initially presented to you was `[u8]`? (Thus you called `serde_json::from_slice` on it). Would sending that verbatim and decoding it on the receiver side work?

Comment: It seems that this just isn't supported by `bincode`: https://docs.rs/bincode/1.2.0/bincode/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.DeserializeAnyNotSupported But I don't know much about that

Comment: @edwardw It comes from  a `hyper::Chunk`. Unfortunately I need to serialize it into the struct for other purposes before publishing it to RabbitMQ. Though I might be able to clone it and publish the raw chunk anyway.

Comment: @edwardw It worked! I now publish the `hyper::Chunk` verbatim to RabbitMQ and deserialze it using `serde _json` in the consumer without any problems.